# Change from Decorator to Control

Tags: wpf, controls, decorator

sorry for the new question, but for my old one I have found a solution. I want to have a bindablePasswordBox and have found [this](https://gist.github.com/468331) example. Now i am trying to integrate this code into my project. It works like I want, but there is one problem left. Because I want to base the style of my BindablePasswordBox to an other control I have to change it from a decorator like in the example, to a control like in the code here:

```
    public class BindablePasswordBox : Control
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordProperty;

        private bool isPreventCallback;
        private RoutedEventHandler savedCallback;

        static BindablePasswordBox()
        {
            PasswordProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Password",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(BindablePasswordBox),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPasswordPropertyChanged))
            );
        }

        public BindablePasswordBox()
        {
            savedCallback = HandlePasswordChanged;

            PasswordBox passwordBox = new PasswordBox();
            passwordBox.PasswordChanged += savedCallback;
            **Child** = passwordBox;
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get { return GetValue(PasswordProperty) as string; }
            set { SetValue(PasswordProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnPasswordPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            BindablePasswordBox customPasswordBox = (BindablePasswordBox)d;
            PasswordBox passwordBox = (PasswordBox)customPasswordBox.**Child**;

            if (customPasswordBox.isPreventCallback)
            {
                return;
            }

            passwordBox.PasswordChanged -= customPasswordBox.savedCallback;
            passwordBox.Password = (eventArgs.NewValue != null) ? eventArgs.NewValue.ToString() : "";
            passwordBox.PasswordChanged += customPasswordBox.savedCallback;
        }

        private void HandlePasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            PasswordBox passwordBox = (PasswordBox)sender;

            isPreventCallback = true;
            Password = passwordBox.Password;
            isPreventCallback = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I get two mistakes underlined by Visual Studio. I have marked this two position in bold letters. Both "Child" are marked as mistakes.

Please help me and give me a hint to solve this problem. I am a newbie to wpf so please help me.

Seppo

Comment: `Control` does not have `Child`. It has `Content` instead.

Comment: Do you mean, that I just can change the to Child by Content? That doesn't work :(

Comment: Sorry, was mistaken. You can change your base class from `Control` to `ContentControl` so `Content` will be available.

Answer (score 0):

[Child](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.decorator.child.aspx) is only defined as part of [Decorator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.decorator.aspx).

Comment: Do you know a workaround for that, so the bindablePasswordBox do the same but just is a control and no decorator?